# Printing out a Linked list

Tags: java, string, printing, linked-list

When I try to print out my linked list of objects it gives me this:

linkedlist.MyLinkedList@329f3d

Is there a way to simply overide this to print as Strings?

```
package linkedlist;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String item;

        MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();
        System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + list.size());

        Object item1 = "one";
        Object item2 = "two";
        Object item3 = "Three";

        list.add(item1);
        list.add(item2);
        list.add(item3);

        System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + list.size());

        System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what programming language you use. However, a related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372976/c-print-linked-list-of-strings

Answer (score 11):

If your list implements the java.util.list interface you can use, this line to convert the list to an array and print out the array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, by default every class in java got `toString` method from `Object` class.
The `toString` method from `Object class` will print `class name` followed with `@` and `hash code`.

You can [override toString method](http://www.slideshare.net/fmshaon/effective-java-always-override-tostring-method) for the `LinkedList`.
For example:

```
class MyLinkedList extends LinkedList
{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyLinkedList [size=" + size + ", first=" + first + ", last="
                + last + ", modCount=" + modCount + "]";
    }

}
```

Then you can print it:

```
 MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList ();
 System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can derive the linked list class and override the toString method...