# How can I return in a GTK function in C a list of characters with GSList?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, filechooser

I need to save the path of each file contained in a folder.
This is the code:

```
void on_file1_file_set(GtkFileChooserButton *chooser){
 GSList filelist;
 printf("file name = %s\n", gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(chooser)));
 printf("folder uri = %s\n", gtk_file_chooser_get_uri(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(chooser)));    
 printf("folder filenames = %s\n", gtk_file_chooser_get_filenames(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(chooser)));
 return filelist;
}
```

and my error:

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘GSList *’ {aka ‘struct _GSList *’} [-Wformat=]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you are passing the wrong type of argument into the string formatter. In your third `printf()` statement you are passing in the return value from `gtk_file_chooser_get_filenames()` which is of type `GSList`, not `char`.

All you need is to use the return value from that function. It is the GSList you are looking for.

```
void on_file1_file_set(GtkFileChooserButton *chooser){
 GSList *filelist;
 filelist = gtk_file_chooser_get_filenames(GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(chooser));
 return filelist;
}
```

Comment: Now how could I show that information contained in the GSList in the console? to verify that it is saved correctly?

Comment: That would be a duplicate question, I'm sure there are answers out there. A `GSList` is a singly linked list. Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372976/c-print-linked-list-of-strings. Just go from there.